# Solve the following differential equation by the Laplace transform method: $y''+y'= 8x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, laplace-transform

Solve the following differential equation by the Laplace transform method:

$y''+y'= 8x^2, \\ y(0)=0 , \\ y'(0)=1$

By applying the Laplace transform to both sides:

$L\{y''+y'\}=L\{8x^2\}$

$L\{y''+y'\}=s^2L\{y\}-sy(0)-y'(0)+sL\{y\}-y'(0)$

$L\{8x^2\}=\frac{16}{s^3}$

Then

$s^2L\{y\}-sy(0)-y'(0)+sL\{y\}-y(0)= \frac{16}{s^3}$

When entering initial conditions
$y(0)=0 \\ y'(0)=1$

$s^2L\{y\}- s(0)-1+sL\{y\}-0=\frac{16}{s^3}$
By simplifying

$s^2L\{y\}+sL\{y\} -1 =\frac{16}{s^3}$

When solving for $L\{y\}: L\{y\}= \frac{16+s^3}{s^4(1+s)}$

Applying the inverse Lapalace transform:

$y= L^{-1} \{ \frac{16+s^3}{s^4(1+s)}\}$

$y= -15+16x-8x^2+ \frac{8x^3}{3}+15e^{-x}$

I want to know if this result is correct guys

Comment: Substitute your result in the differential equation and see whether it is satisfied.

Comment: You can use Mathematica to verify your result. `DSolve[y''[x] + y'[x] == 8 x^2, y, x]` $\frac{8 x^3}{3}-8 x^2+16 x-c_1 e^{-x}+c_2$ your result seems correct.

Comment: @Gonçalo is right.  It is easy to check whether this is a solution!

Comment: Do I calculate the first and second derivative of the expression?

Comment: Yes. And don't forget to check whether your solution also satisfies $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The result you obtained is correct. We elaborate some of the steps here. We have the differential equation:

$$ y'' + y' = 8x^2 $$

with $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$. Taking the Laplace transform we get:

$$ s^2Y(s) - 1 + sY(s) = \frac{16}{s^3}$$

We rewrite as:

$$ Y(s) = \frac{16 + s^3}{s^4(s + 1)} $$

Applying partial fraction decomposition we get:

$$ Y(s) = \frac{16}{s^4} - \frac{16}{s^3} + \frac{16}{s^2} + \frac{15}{s + 1} - \frac{15}{s} $$

Using the following two identities:

$$ L \left(x^n\right) = \frac{n!}{s^{n + 1}} $$
$$ L \left( e^{ax} \right) = \frac{1}{s - a}$$

we take the inverse transform and get:

$$ y(x) = \frac{8}{3} x^3 - 8x^2 + 16x + 15e^{-x} - 15 $$

which is the result you obtained.